# onHandler(Intent intent) method of IntentService gets called multiple times

Tags: android

We are loading a large amount of data from SQLite db, and using IntentService.

There is an activity which receives broadcast from IntentService when loading is complete. When trying to launch the activity before the IntentService is complete, the `onHandler(Intent intent)` method gets called multiple times.

*Intent Service is started on Application start up.*

```
 public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    startService(new Intent(this, QuoteService.class);  
 }
```

*Intent Service*

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.v("Intent","Handler Intent");
    DataAccessObject dof=new DataAccessObject(getApplicationContext());
    ........
`........` *// data loaded from Data Access Object*
```

sendPersonListBroadcast();

```
    *//  method which sends Broadcast to Activity*
```

Comment: Is it possible Android is killing and reviving your service due to memory constraints?

Comment: Is the onStartCommand(...) in the service getting called? Is onStartCommand or onCreate in the service also getting called multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Are there one more process in your application? It will calls the `onCreate` in your Application each process.